# Splitting contents in index of column total to other columns in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, split, sum, calculation

I have a large data frame with many columns. In creating subtotal rows for columns, I have run into the issue where the rows that contain totals have in the index the subtotal's identifying label, instead of in a column of the data frame, and information from the sum operation is amalgamated in a string in columns.

My first goal is to split up the string in the index that identifies the subtotal and place it in other columns, but doing so is proving difficult. My second goal is to get rid of the amalgamated string in the right-most column of non-numeric data in the subtotal row.

Original:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'Status':['Active','Active','Inactive','Active'], 'Source':['Domestic','International','International','Restricted'], 'Activity':['In Progress','Post','Post','In Progress'], 'FY20':[2,55,52,99],'FY21':[90,20,11,43],'FY22':[10,52,57,9]})



#sorted
df['Status'] = pd.Categorical(df['Status'],categories= ['Inactive','Active'])
df = df.sort_values('Status')
df['Source'] = pd.Categorical(df['Source'],categories= ['International','Restricted','Domestic'])
df = df.sort_values('Source')

#taking the sum of columns
df.loc['Active - In Progress Subtotal'] = df.loc[(df['Status'].isin(['Active'])) & (df['Activity'].isin(['In Progress']))].sum(axis=0)
```

[image]

Desired Output would be:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'Status':['Active','Active','Inactive','Active','Active'], 'Source':['Domestic','International','International','Restricted','In Progress Subtotal'], 'Activity':['In Progress','Post','Post','In Progress',""], 'FY20':[2,55,52,99,101],'FY21':[90,20,11,43,133],'FY22':[10,52,57,9,19]})

df['Status'] = pd.Categorical(df['Status'],categories= ['Inactive','Active'])
df = df.sort_values('Status')
df['Source'] = pd.Categorical(df['Source'],categories= ['International','Restricted','Domestic','In Progress Subtotal'])
df = df.sort_values('Source')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
# your dataframe:
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Status": ["Active", "Active", "Inactive", "Active"],
        "Source": ["Domestic", "International", "International", "Restricted"],
        "Activity": ["In Progress", "Post", "Post", "In Progress"],
        "FY20": [2, 55, 52, 99],
        "FY21": [90, 20, 11, 43],
        "FY22": [10, 52, 57, 9],
    }
)

# sorted
df["Status"] = pd.Categorical(df["Status"], categories=["Inactive", "Active"])
df = df.sort_values("Status")
df["Source"] = pd.Categorical(
    df["Source"], categories=["International", "Restricted", "Domestic"]
)
df = df.sort_values("Source")



# create desired boolean mask
mask = df["Status"].eq("Active") & df["Activity"].eq("In Progress")

# make the sum
x = df.loc[mask, "FY20":].sum()

# what should the rest of the columns contain?
x.loc["Status"] = "Active"
x.loc["Source"] = "In Progress Subtotal"
x.loc["Activity"] = ""

# add it to the original dataframe
print(pd.concat([df, x.to_frame().T], ignore_index=True))
```

Prints:

```
     Status                Source     Activity FY20 FY21 FY22
0  Inactive         International         Post   52   11   57
1    Active         International         Post   55   20   52
2    Active            Restricted  In Progress   99   43    9
3    Active              Domestic  In Progress    2   90   10
4    Active  In Progress Subtotal               101  133   19
```